# Creating jquery function for image opacity animation doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation, filter

```
function color_fadein(element,val1){
    $(this).children(element).stop().animate({
    opacity: val1,
    }, 200);
}

function color_fadeout(element,val2){
    $(this).children(element).stop().animate({
    opacity: val2,
    }, 200);
}

$('.post').hover(color_fadein('img','0.5'),color_fadeout('img', '1'));
```

Why isn't this working? chrome developer tools doesn't return any error however it doesnt work. Please help me out

Comment: You're calling `op_fadein` and `op_fadeout` at the same time in .hover(). They will conflict with each other as the animation time are equal. Either set a delay or create one function which executes the second animation after the first one is complete with the callback (see jQuery animation documentation).

Comment: I thought that .hover() accepts two functions: first for when the mouse is over the specific element and the second one for when the mouse is no longer over that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper function : and pass `this` :  ( also I would use `find` and not  `children` so it seeks deeper)

```
function op_fadein(t,element,val1){

    $(t).find(element).stop().animate({
    opacity: val1,
    }, 200);
}

function op_fadeout(t,element,val2){

    $(t).find(element).stop().animate({
    opacity: val2,
    }, 200);
}

$('.post').hover(function (){op_fadein(this,'img','0.5')},function (){op_fadeout(this,'img', '1')});
```

http://jsbin.com/OgOdak/1/edit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass through `this` into the function like this if 'img' is not a direct descendent use .find() instead of children()

```
function op_fadein(that, element, val1) {
    $(that).children(element).stop().animate({
        opacity: val1,
    }, 200);
}

function op_fadeout(that, element, val2) {
    $(that).children(element).stop().animate({
        opacity: val2,
    }, 200);
}
```

Add `function(){}` in hover like this

```
$('.post').hover(function () {
    op_fadein(this, 'img', '0.5')
}, function () {
    op_fadeout(this, 'img', '1')
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/agCeL/)